# Why background image width stretch longer than screen (browser)?

Tags: background, repeat, stretch

My website is responsive, but my background image keep stretch longer than screen (or browser) which make browser has scroll bar on the bottom because of an extra portion width to the right? My main contents are responsive. So this extra portion just background image.
If i added "background-repeat: no-repeat;" then there is still extra white color portion to the right which still make it extra that has scroll bar
If i removed the background image, there is also an extra white portion stretch to the right the same.

Here is my style.css

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    background: url(../images/wood_background.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the width using

Example:`background:size:100% 100%`

You can adjust the percentage so that your image is adjusted accordingly

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Thank you for your help